# A question regarding a linear transformation in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been trying to solve this one from sometime, but unable to. Saw it in a sample paper I was trying to solve. Here it is: 
Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear transformation. Show that there exists a line $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $T(L)=L$.

Comment: do you know eigenvector?

Comment: This isn't actually true unless you require that $T$ is invertible, or weaken the conclusion to $T(L)\subseteq L$.

Comment: @Matt I would surmise that $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ implies invertibility, but you are right in pointing out that subtlety.

Comment: @adamW I would find that convention very unusual. For a start, it would mean that the set of all such $T$ doesn't form a vector space.

Comment: @MattPressland I suspected it may be unconventional, since writing $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ would imply the number of inputs of 3 vs. 2 outputs. I was thinking that $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ implied $T$ was onto $\mathbb{R}^3$ (as opposed to into if my terminology is correct). At least that was the only way I could see to percieve the question to be correct, since otherwise it is asking for a (technically) impossible proof.

Comment: @adamW That is reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assume $0$ is not an eigenvalue, ie $T$ is invertible. Otherwise, this may be false. Take $T=0$ for instance.

Hint: every degree $3$ real polynomial has a real root.